# Difference in UI using JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

In this link given below

https://jsfiddle.net/glkc93/675nb8yf/

I have created a UI design using HTML and JS code seperately. But i observed that the output is a little different, 
- output by HTML code has spaces between buttons
- output by JS code do not.

I went to developer tools to check the final code and both are same. 
Why is this difference observed??

Attaching code:
HTML:

```
<div id="res" class="result"></div>
<div id="btns" class="container">
  <button id="btn0" class="button number">0</button>
  <button id="btn1" class="button number">1</button>
  <button id="btnClr" class="button final">C</button>
  <button id="btnEql" class="button final">=</button>
  <button id="btnSum" class="button operation">+</button>
  <button id="btnSub" class="button operation">-</button>
  <button id="btnMul" class="button operation">*</button>
  <button id="btnDiv" class="button operation">/</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var result = document.createElement("div");
result.setAttribute('id', 'res');
result.setAttribute('class', 'result');
document.body.appendChild(result);

var btns = document.createElement("div");
btns.setAttribute('id', 'btns');
btns.setAttribute('class', 'container');

var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
btn1.setAttribute('id', 'btn1');
btn1.setAttribute('class', 'button number');
btn1.innerHTML = '1';

var btn0 = document.createElement("button");
btn0.setAttribute('id', 'btn0');
btn0.setAttribute('class', 'button number');
btn0.innerHTML = '0';

var btnClr = document.createElement("button");
btnClr.setAttribute('id', 'btnClr');
btnClr.setAttribute('class', 'button final');
btnClr.innerHTML = 'C';

var btnEql = document.createElement("button");
btnEql.setAttribute('id', 'btnEql');
btnEql.setAttribute('class', 'button final');
btnEql.innerHTML = '=';

var btnSum = document.createElement("button");
btnSum.setAttribute('id', 'btnSum');
btnSum.setAttribute('class', 'button operation');
btnSum.innerHTML = '+';

var btnSub = document.createElement("button");
btnSub.setAttribute('id', 'btnSub');
btnSub.setAttribute('class', 'button operation');
btnSub.innerHTML = '-';

var btnMul = document.createElement("button");
btnMul.setAttribute('id', 'btnMul');
btnMul.setAttribute('class', 'button operation');
btnMul.innerHTML = '*';

var btnDiv = document.createElement("button");
btnDiv.setAttribute('id', 'btnDiv');
btnDiv.setAttribute('class', 'button operation');
btnDiv.innerHTML = '/';

btns.appendChild(btn0);
btns.appendChild(btn1);
btns.appendChild(btnClr);
btns.appendChild(btnEql);
btns.appendChild(btnSum);
btns.appendChild(btnSub);
btns.appendChild(btnMul);
btns.appendChild(btnDiv);

document.body.appendChild(btns);
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 90%
}

.result {
  width: 81%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.button {
  width: 22%;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.number {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: brown;
}

.final {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
}

.operation {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Spaces are characters in HTML, the spaces you have for your new line/indentations count as "text nodes" and have a small visual representation, which you see as the spaces between the buttons. In Javascript when using `appendChild`, there are no extra spaces between elements as there are in the HTML and thus the buttons will not have spaces between them. If you were to re-format your HTML so all of the buttons were on a single line with no spaces between the start & closing tags, you would get the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because while loading as Html it adds Some Extra Characters as textNodes.
this is because of the indentation you gave in the html.

[image]

But while inserting nodes via JS this won't happen.
By Js you won't add any textNodes hence no spacing is seen inbetween

```
<div id="res" class="result"></div>
<div id="btns" class="container">
  <button id="btn0" class="button number">0</button>
  <button id="btn1" class="button number">1</button>
```

Try giving minified using minifier or remove indendation as shown below

```
<div id="res" class="result"></div><div id="btns" class="container"><button id="btn0" class="button number">0</button><button id="btn1" class="button number">1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some day text-space-collapse: discard; may work ... but in the mean time you can just add a negative spacing to your css container for the buttons.

```
.container {
  letter-spacing: -0.25em;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Be careful though. This would be not be appropriate if your container contains meaningful space. You also may want to add:

```
letter-spacing: normal;
```

to your child containers like .button so the text there would not be messed with.

Note: I tested with your jsfiddle and it seems to work.